# Set operators problem when trying to find MIN and MAX date for a condition

Tags: sql-server, select, operators

I want to find the minimum and maximum date on which a given product had a maximum unit cost, but only of the unit cost had a value of more than 10.

The result that I should get should be something like this:

[image: example result]

If the date is the minimum `date_type` is `MIN`, and vice-versa.

This is the script that I tried, but I only get two records:

```
select MIN(dt) as min_date, MAX(dt) as max_date
from products
WHERE price = (SELECT max(price) FROM products where unit_id =1)
```

Products table:

[image]

Unit table:

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. [Here](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) is a great place to start.

Comment: Images of data and results are not great. [Why?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) What are you expecting as output from this sample data?